# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: “2,3456” (at offset 5)

Tags: java, android, localization, locale, number-formatting

I am trying to get a double value from a Philippines number. "2,3456".

This is how I'm trying to do.

```
try {
    return NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("en","PH")).parse("2,3456").doubleValue(); 
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

I'm getting unparseable exception for Philippines, but if I use same code for Indonesia with Indonesia locale with String "2.3456" it is working fine.

What is the issue with Philippines locale?

Comment: Do Philippines use "," as the decimal separator? If not, use "." instead.

Comment: @Tom "," is a thousand seperator. I'm just trying to parse the string I'm receiving

Comment: It seems to work fine: http://ideone.com/okLW5W

Comment: @Beginner Oh ok, misunderstood that. But like assylias said, the posted code works fine (for me). It returns `23456.0`.

Comment: @Beginner The ``,`` is not a thousand seperator if your input is ``2,3456``.

Comment: @f1sh The thousand separator doesn't need to be in the correct place in order to be parsable. `"2,3,4,56"` also works fine, even though it looks wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The Phillipines use a dot as the decimal separator and the comma as the thousands separator. But 2,3456 is valid under the Phillipines  locale since the parser is lapse about the positions of the thousands separator.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark

Comment: This is not quite right, because `"2,3456"` can be correctly parsed (`"2,3,4,56"` as well). The parser isn't that strict about the position of the thousand separator, since it doesn't matter anyway. It won't change the resulting number.

Comment: even if comma is at different place also it should work fine